# How do i associate a model_id to a nested model of third level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

my model structure looks like this

```
resources :genres do
  resources :stories do
     resources :episodes do
        resources :comments
     end
  end
end
```

I have already added an episode_id to the comments table. However when i added genre_id and story_id to comments table and check for it in the console, genre_id and story_id was given Nil.
`

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :episode
  belongs_to :story
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Genre.rb

```
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stories, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Story.rb

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :genre
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
has_many :episodes, dependent: :destroy

has_attached_file :image, size: { less_than: 1.megabyte }, styles:{      medium: "300x300#", wide: "200x400#" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

scope :of_followed_users, -> (following_users) { where user_id: following_users }
```

end

Comment: why not polymorphic associations for comments?

Comment: Yes, i have thought of that, but there are features i implemented directly to the comments of which i have issues with when used polymorphic associations at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can't associate comment belongs to more models without set `otional: true`, because your comment will require ids for all associated models.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :episode, optional: true
  belongs_to :story, optional: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I sugest you to use this example.

change comment table with this migration

```
def change
  add_column :comments, :commentable_type, :string
  add_column :comments, :commentable_id, :integer
  add_column :comments, :user_id, :integer
end
```

---

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable,  polymorphic: true 
end
```

---

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

---

```
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, depented: :destroy
end
```

---

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, depented: :destroy
end
```

---

now you can `Story.last.comments.new` => `.., commentable_id: story_last_id, commentable_type: 'Story'`

[more about polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Comment: I'll try that straight up and give you a feedback.

Comment: Could you please explain how to setup a mailer for the comment since things have changed a little... i.e whenever a comment is made on an episode which belongs to story and story to genre.

Comment: use `after_create` callback  in model `Comment`. This is another question. I think you should create new question.